# wireshark and port forwarding

Tags: wireshark, portforwarding

I am a complete novice to this...  I have a webcam behind my router, and it's configured to be accessible on a particular port (e.g. 30000) using a port forwarding configuration. It has a fixed IP in my network.

Using wireshark, I can see the camera responding to requests coming from within my network (i.e. another client), and this does not use port forwarding.

However, when I access the camera from outside my network (i.e. using external IP plus port), wireshark does not show anything (but I see the camera streaming on the client).

I use wireshark on ubuntu, eth0, and ip.addr == 192.168.x.y as filter

Answer (score 0):

When the camera was streaming data to the internal client, were you also capturing packets with Wireshark on that same client?  I'm guessing that you were, which is why you saw the data.

When the camera streams to a client on an external network, the stream flows through the router, but your client is likely plugged into another switch port on the back of your router, and the router doesn't forward the packets to that port, which is why you don't see them.

In order to observe the packets, you would need to configure your capture PC such that it can capture the packets.  There are a few different methods to achieve this, for example, using a hub, a SPAN/mirror port on a managed switch if you have one, or a TAP.  I would recommend reading the detailed information available on the Wireshark [Ethernet capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) wiki page, which describes several different methods for successfully capturing Ethernet frames and provides helpful pictures as well.  Choose a capture scenario that best meets your needs (and $$ budget).